# to put border-pixel and border-radius around images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create a container which hold a div with image
but around image  I should to create another element `border: 1px solid #C7B273;` in four party:

top, bottom, left, right and give another property necessary for border px  around image.

Image has border-radius:0;
By the UI/UX I understand that  `border: 1px solid #C7B273;` should  to stay `margin-bottom` after picture.

I try to do this:

```css
img {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
    <img src="./images/about.jpg" width="200px" height="256px" alt="Nature">
</div>
```

And get this results:

[image]

But result final should be like image:

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you dont mixed result image with should be image???

Comment: If you want to set the image off against its border "position", then you need to apply the border to an element that wraps the image to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```css
.w {
  height: 256px;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
}     
img {
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
    <div class="border">
      <div class="w"></div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900/gray" width="200px" height="256px" alt="Nature">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
     
.border {
  height: 256px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
} 
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.div {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #C7B273;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
z-index: -1
}
```

```html
  <div class="border">
  <img
  class="image"
  src="https://placeimg.com/200/256/nature"
  width="200px"
  height="256px"
  alt="Nature"
  />
  <div class="div"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, please can explain to understand much better or can send me any links about this.
Thanks .

Comment: hassan souiti Thanks a lot for your answer, please can explain to understand much better or can send me any links about this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, you add a div after the image and this one which you add the styles (the border behind the picture).
position: absolute -   width: 95%;-   height: 95%; -  bottom: -10px; -  left: -10px; to control the position ( from bottom and left)
z-index: -1 to put it behind the picture.

you can read about the position here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: hassan souiti thanks for your answer but way we should use class .border in first dive?

Comment: hassan souiti thanks for your answer but way we should use class .border in first dive? 

and inside a class image we have put   class="image"
  src="https://placeimg.com/200/256/nature"
  width="200px"
  height="256px"



And way we  have set aging into style css ..image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;}
?